# Display specific column name in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I am using laravel 5.6. I've two tables. One is **Teachers(id,name,email,salary)** another is **Students(id,teacher_id,name,email)** I have joined 2 tables

```
$vu_data = Teacher::join('Students', 'teachers.id', '=', 'students.teacher_id')
                           ->where('teachers.id', $id)
                           ->get();
return view('view_full')->with('vu_data',$vu_data);
```

**view_full.blade.php**

```
{{$vu_data[0]->name}}
```

How can I display sthdent name and teacher nam. There are same column name.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way is to use laravel Eloquent relationships [https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).
Put on your Teachers model

```
public function students(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Students', 'teacher_id', 'id');

    }
```

You will call like that:

```
$vu_data->students()
```

If you want to use yur select, simple use de 'AS'

```
->select('Teachers.name as teacher_name', 'Students.name as student_name')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. what should be returns from controller like **return view('view_full')->with('vu_data',$vu_data);** It's new for me. please don't mind

Comment: What do you mean by "returns from controller like return view('view_full')->with('vu_data',$vu_data); " ? It's pretty clear, 1. add relationship....2. Pass data from controller to blade....3. Then view in blade.There is nothing to do anything additionally

Comment: Yeah, you will just pass like "->with('vu_data',$vu_data)"
On your view you'll need a foreach loop to acces each student individually:
foreach($vu_data->students()->get as $student)

Some people dont like to call moddel methods on views, but this is for another question rsrs

Comment: Sorry . I want to pass data from controller

Comment: Another way to pass to the view
->with('vu_data',$vu_data)->with('students', $vu_data->students()->get())

Comment: ok. please don't bother to me. how can i compare like **->where('teachers.id', $id)**

Comment: Just like you do, but without JOIN
Teacher::where('teachers.id', $id)->get();
The eloquent will make the join for you.

Comment: In your above suggestion can u give me controller code so that i can pass that to view page?

Comment: I did not understand the question.
Is that?
$vu_data = Teacher::where('teachers.id', $id)->get();
return view('view_full')
 ->with('vu_data',$vu_data)
  ->with('students',$vu_data->students()->get());

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DuPRlfshT_JQ1iRkUQTViITZ0h8bD_mvoprgfm7c25c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: As per the table structure in question, its is Not `many-to-many`. The teacher_id stored in students table with no separate table `student_teacher` table.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify the columns in a `select()` clause on the query, and rename the columns. Such as

```
Teacher::join('Students', 'teachers.id', '=', 'students.teacher_id')
     ->where('teachers.id', $id)
     ->select('teachers.name AS teacher_name', 'students.name AS student_name', [ rest of columns])
     ->get();
```

However, you might want to look into [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships), which will allow you to iterate through a teacher then all of that teacher's students, or vice versa.

Comment: If you use the select like above, you would use `{{$vu_data[0]->teacher_name}}` to get the value out. Otherwise, no. It doesn't pass the table name back to the object, and objects do not like duplicate property names.

Comment: Save some time with `select(['teachers.*', 'students.*', 'teachers.name as t_name', 'students.name as s_name'])`. Later selects override previous ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add before ->get()

```
->select('Teachers.name as teacherName', 'Students.name as studentName')
```

and than you can use

```
{{$vu_data[0]->teacherName}}
```

and

```
{{$vu_data[0]->studentName}}
```

Comment: no, after as you can specify it to be teacherName, teacher_name etc just don't use dot because it will screw SQL syntax and also ->teachers.name is not allowed in PHP

Comment: I have too many same columns. I just showed u some of them. how can I do that ?

Comment: Than spend some time and ignore "join", do it using Eloquent relationships https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many so it will be $uv_data[0]->students()->name, I answered here on specific solution you asked for

Answer (score 0):

As per your table structure `one teacher has many students`. Hence instead of using join you can use laravel relationships with `hasMany` :

Teacher has many students - `Teacher` Model :

```
public function students(){

   return $this->hasMany(Students::class);

}
```

A student belongs to a teacher - `Student` Model :

```
public function teacher(){

   return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class);
}
```

Now you can get relationships like below :

Get all teachers with their students :

```
$teachers = Teacher::with('students')->get();
```

Get all students of a particular techer :

```
$teacher = Teacher::find($teacherId);
$students = $teacher->students;
```

Finally using this, you can convert this :

```
$vu_data = Teacher::join('Students', 'teachers.id', '=', 'students.teacher_id')
                           ->where('teachers.id', $id)
                           ->get();
return view('view_full')->with('vu_data',$vu_data);
```

To this :

```
$teacher = Teacher::find($id);

return view('view_full', compact('teacher'));
```

Then inside blade :

You can get teacher details :  `{{ $teacher->name }}`

and students :

```
@if($teacher->students->count() > 0)

    @foreach($teacher->students as $student)
      {{ $student->name }} 
    @endforech

@endif
```